# FactoryGirl: Factory not registered for Engine project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've gone through these pages and tried many things found on those pages:

[FactoryGirl: Factory not registered: user (ArgumentError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409787/factorygirl-factory-not-registered-user-argumenterror)
[Cannot get factory_girl running under rails 3.0.5,unexpected tCONSTANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298392/cannot-get-factory-girl-running-under-rails-3-0-5-unexpected-tconstant)
['Factory not registered' error in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690351/factory-not-registered-error-in-rails-4)
[FactoryGirl: Factory not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299078/factorygirl-factory-not-registered)

but keep getting "Factory not registered: user"

The file test/factories.rb (also tried test/factories/user_factory.rb) looks like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    login 'mbrown@yahoo.com'
    email 'mbrown@yahoo.com'
  end
end
```

Stub for test:

```
  it 'just_a_test_of_testing' do
    u = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
```

Doesn't work, gives me "ArgumentError: Factory not registered: user"

Does anyone know the "right solution"? It seems likely it is "engine" related, but I just don't know what to try next, any ideas? Maybe it has something to do with the fact that User is a model of the test/dummy app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure definitions path in spec/support/factory_girl.rb file as [FactoryGirl documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#configure-your-test-suite) suggests?

```
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = %w(custom_factories_directory)
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Comment: That file doesn't exist; if I create it and add that, it seems to have no affect. I have tried creating it for the engine and for the app

Answer (score 0):

A coworker got it going, his class looks like

```
Module MyEngineMod
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user, class: User do
       # content not shown 
    end
  end
end
```

So it seems it needed to be name-spaced at least, and maybe needs the class: attribute too.

Comment: Do not use the constantized class name (`User`) in your factory definitions... it will eager load the model and is likely to cause performance problems with your tests (see FactoryBot README https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#specifying-the-class-explicitly)... also you have module capitalized in there. A better approach here is to remove the module wrapper and and just pass the modulized stringified class name (`class: 'MyEngineMod::User'`)